# Emoji to Hex value in ios

Tags: ios, emoji

I want to know how to convert the emoji to hex value.That is for the smiley having 'SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND SMILING EYES' (*smiley corresponds to :)* ) I should get "1F604"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
NSString *smiley = @"";

NSData *data = [smiley dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
uint32_t unicode;
[data getBytes:&unicode length:sizeof(unicode)];
NSLog(@"%x", unicode);
// Output: 1f604
```

Reverse direction:

```
uint32_t unicode = 0x1f604;

NSString *smiley = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&unicode length:sizeof(unicode) encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", smiley);
// Output:
```

*Remark:* Both code examples assume that integers are stored in *little-endian byte order* (which is the case for all current platforms running OS X or iOS).

Comment: @Martin.Thank you for your answer.I have one more doubt,how to achieve the reverse ie from '1f604' to the smiley

Comment: Thank you so much.It works for initial set of smiley in iOS emoji key board.But for the last set i.e. starting from 1,2…# with blue border,it gives the hex value as '31' for emoji '1' and after converting to emoji I am getting digit '1' Not smiley

Comment: @Jeff: "1⃣" is not a single character, but two characters: "1" followed by U+20E3 = COMBINING ENCLOSING KEYCAP ...

Comment: For the last set of emojis,after the conversion of uint32_t to smiley,Almost all characters are not as expected.Any help will be appreciable ??

Comment: How i can convert NSString *smiley = @"This is a happy "; ?

Answer (score 1):

**Swift Version**

```
let smiley = ""

let uni = smiley.unicodeScalars // Unicode scalar values of the string
let unicode = uni[uni.startIndex].value // First element as an UInt32

println(String(unicode, radix: 16, uppercase: true))
// Output: 1F60A
```