# Convert emoji to hex value using Swift

Tags: swift, hex, emoji

I'm trying to convert emojis in hex values, I found [some code online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427680/emoji-to-hex-value-in-ios) to do it but it's only working using Objective C, how to do the same with Swift?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a "pure Swift" method, without using Foundation:

```
let smiley = ""

let uni = smiley.unicodeScalars // Unicode scalar values of the string
let unicode = uni[uni.startIndex].value // First element as an UInt32

print(String(unicode, radix: 16, uppercase: true))
// Output: 1F60A
```

Note that a Swift `Character` represents a "Unicode grapheme cluster"
(compare [Strings in Swift 2](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=30) from the Swift blog) which can 
consist of several "Unicode scalar values". Taking the example
from @TomSawyer's comment below:

```
let zero = "0️⃣"

let uni = zero.unicodeScalars // Unicode scalar values of the string
let unicodes = uni.map { $0.value }

print(unicodes.map { String($0, radix: 16, uppercase: true) } )
// Output: ["30", "FE0F", "20E3"]
```

Comment: doesn't work with combination emoji like 0️⃣ , ‍❤️‍‍

Comment: @TomSawyer: `0️⃣` consists of three Unicode code points: U+0030 (the character "0"), followed by U+FE0F (VARIATION SELECTOR-16) and U+20E3 (COMBINING ENCLOSING KEYCAP) – What do you think the correct output should be?

Comment: @TomSawyer: `‍❤️‍‍` is not even a single character, it is the *String* composed of the characters `"‍", "❤️‍", "‍", ""`.

Comment: @TomSawyer: Some feedback how it "doesn't work" and what the correct output should be (in your opinion) would be much appreciated ...

Comment: @MartinR Any way to get the name of emoji like- :smile:, :angry: and so on ?

Comment: @iDeveloper: This might be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24699576/1187415.

Comment: Hey @MartinR I go through this before, But It's giving me full description of emoji, Instead of just name. What i am looking for just name of selected emoji. Example- If I selected  So I want the name emoji e.g. blush

Comment: @iDeveloper: I am sorry but I cannot help you with that. I do not know if such a method exists.

Answer (score 6):

If some one trying to found a way to convert **Emoji To Unicode** string

```
extension String {

  func decode() -> String {
      let data = self.data(using: .utf8)!
      return String(data: data, encoding: .nonLossyASCII) ?? self
  }

  func encode() -> String {
      let data = self.data(using: .nonLossyASCII, allowLossyConversion: true)!
      return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
  }
}
```

Example:

1. "".encode()

**RESULT:** \ud83d\ude0d

2. "\ud83d\ude0d".decode()

**RESULT:**

Comment: this works fine, but there is a problem with characters in other languages: For example: "Ä" -- this letter is not encoding properly with the above way

Answer (score 1):

It works similarly but pay attention when you're printing it:

```
import Foundation

var smiley = ""
var data: NSData = smiley.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!
var unicode:UInt32 = UInt32()
data.getBytes(&unicode)
// println(unicode) // Prints the decimal value
println(NSString(format:"%2X", unicode)) // Print the hex value of the smiley
```