# How can get unicode of an emoji in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, emoji

I am new to swift programming.I am working in an app of emoji.When i click an emoji from Apple keyboard it show the unicode of that emoji.How can i get this.

Comment: If you want to get the unicode of a emoji in swift you should take a look at: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27278005/2164516

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Swift Unicode escape sequence concept:

```
let emojiString = "\u{1F4C4}"
```

and if you want to get all emoji's Unicode then try this

```
let emojiRanges = [
    0x1F601...0x1F64F,
    0x2702...0x27B0,
    0x1F680...0x1F6C0,
    0x1F170...0x1F251
]

for range in emojiRanges {
    for i in range {
        var c = String(UnicodeScalar(i))
        print(c)
    }
}
```

Comment: When i click an emoji from Apple keyboard it show the unicode of that emoji.How can i get this.

Comment: @YaseenKhan just use that Unicode wherever you want like for eg if you want that emoji with your label then concat that emoji Unicode with your text message and assign to that label

Comment: Please send me that code.I shall be very thank full

Comment: I need the unicode when i press the emoji form the apple keyboard.

Comment: @YaseenKhanI would like to send you the exact code but first let me know what exactly you want to archive? like I don't know what you want to do

Comment: I want that when the user press any one emoji from keyboard it show the unicode of the emoji that, this emoji is press and the unicode of that emoji is this...

Comment: @YaseenKhan you can get directly from textFieldDelegateMethods for example .    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        
        
        if textField == yourtextField {
            
      print(textField.text)
       }}

Comment: @ Mahesh Dangar Please Send the code.

Comment: @YaseenKhan check above code i have sent you in comment

Comment: @YaseenKhan no need to thanks bro if that code works then please mark as true to my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is list of uicodes

https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

you can also use Edit->Emoji and drag the to the text

```
let str = "Ti \u{1F601} tle"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: When i click an emoji from Apple keyboard it show the unicode of that emoji.How can i get this.